# MySQL use DISTINCT with GROUP BY on same column

Tags: mysql

I currently have a query similar to:

```
select customers.customerId, items.itemName, sum(orders.quantity) as boughtTotal 
from customers join orders on customers.customerId = orders.customerId 
join items on items.itemId = orders.itemId 
group by customers.customerId, items.itemName 
order by boughtTotal desc;
```

The purpose of the query is to relate customers to items they bought, which may span over many orders, and total the amount of each unique item bought. This being achieved with what I have. I want to take this a step further now and select the most popular item for each customer. Since this is ordered with most bought items at the top, I figured I'd just have to add `distinct` next to `customers.customerId` in the `select` statement to have duplicates removed. However, adding `distinct` seems to do nothing. I'd appreciate help in knowing why `distinct` is seemingly doing nothing here, but also how to achieve what I'm trying to do - remove duplicates besides a customer's most popular item.

Tables:

```
customers
 customerId | name 
      1     | John
      2     | Jane

orders
 orderId | customerId | quantity | itemId
    1    |      1     |    11    |   1
    2    |      2     |    13    |   2
    3    |      1     |    4     |   2
    4    |      2     |    14    |   1
    5    |      1     |    1     |   1

items
 itemId | itemName
    1   |    dog
    2   |    cat
```

So from this data the current query will return the following:

```
 customerId | itemName | boughtTotal
      2     |    dog   |     14
      2     |    cat   |     13
      1     |    dog   |     12
      1     |    cat   |     4
```

And what I'd like to have is the following:

```
 customerId | itemName | boughtTotal
      2     |    dog   |     14
      1     |    dog   |     12
```

Comment: add one more condition to ON in JOIN

Comment: In your result set, the two lines for customer 2 are different and so 'distinct' does nothing. The query which you have written will not give you your desired result as you have discovered.

Comment: Use `having` clause along with sub-query which selects max quantity record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;)

```
select t1.*
from (
    select customers.customerId, items.itemName, sum(orders.quantity) as boughtTotal 
    from customers join orders on customers.customerId = orders.customerId 
    join items on items.itemId = orders.itemId
    group by customers.customerId, items.itemName) t1
inner join (
    select max(boughtTotal) as boughtTotal, customerId
    from (
        select customers.customerId, items.itemName, sum(orders.quantity) as boughtTotal 
        from customers join orders on customers.customerId = orders.customerId 
        join items on items.itemId = orders.itemId
        group by customers.customerId, items.itemName)t
    group by customerId) t2 on t1.customerId = t2.customerId and t1.boughtTotal = t2.boughtTotal
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef4d0/1)

Comment: I really cannot thank you enough for this. Worked like a charm. I guess I was thinking there would be a simpler way of doing this and avoided using a subquery.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to achieve this without any subquery, but this query can be optimized to be more simpler.